# Uploading new version of a core file on running website without maintenance mode

Tags: php

Let's say I have a website running on `PHP` using `Kernel` pattern. Let's say I have 1000 requests per second accessing `Kernel.php` file. I want to upload a new version of that file without turning on a maintenance mode. Is it safe to do it? Can I just upload the new file and at some point requests will be handled by this new one?

- `Kernel.php` is error free for sure
- the file is included by `require_once()` in `index.php`
- forget about maintenance mode in this case, please

---

I was told to add some information about why I even thought about that approach.

We are trying to develop a system providing possibility of updating, any part of webpage, driven by our engine. The `Kernel` is just an example - if this file can be modified without maintenance mode, in your opinion, than any other less important might be as well.

Sometimes the update is so simple that turning on maintenance mode is like stopping the military invasion on a country because one of privates (soldier) sneezed.

Since we are talking about blowing up things and inter-process communications: none of us will risk uploading the core files on running website without freezing request for few seconds, but how about template files? It's of course a rhetorical question, but now I think you fully understand all of it.

Comment: That depends on a lot of factors.

Comment: generally speaking, files on unix can be removed/replaced without trouble. Any processes using the old file will keep using a "zombie" copy of it (it won't be really deleted until all open file handles on it are closed), and any new processes will suddenly be using the new file. Question is how will your app react if you've got inter-process communications. process A using the old file talking to process B using the new file... will that blow up anything?

Comment: @MarcB is there something similar on Windows? What phrases should I use to find out this by myself (and update the question if I found something useful)?

Comment: @Paulpro knowing them will allow me to provide more details.

Comment: @TheFrost Well, it depends mostly on the updates to the kernel. For example if you modified the way sessions are stored you could cause every user to lose their sessions and have to log in again.

Comment: @TheFrost: not sure. probably has something similar, but generally windows apps will lock files they're using, or windows does it for the apps automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on PHP opcode caching for your web server, and set the interval to 5 minutes or more.

You can now copy files overtop of running PHP code, and the next time the interval expires the server will check for modifications and recompile the opcode. You'll have to wait a few minutes before you notice the change, because the server will continue to use the cached code until it expires.

I can not advise what would happen if you break dependencies amount PHP files, or if the server will update 1 file but have a different cached copies of other files.

For the most reliable method. You need to use a feature in your web server that allows you to hot swap the directory for a host. You then install a complete new copy of all your PHP code into a new directory, and then hot swap the host to this new location. No requests should be interrupted.

Comment: You mean - having a mirror? And after successful update, switch requests to the new version?

Answer (score 1):

First let me say that this is probably not a very good idea.

Are you running on a Linux server?  If so, renaming files is an atomic operation, and the best way to accomplish this is going to be to upload the new file with a different name, then rename it over the old file.

If not, renaming it over the old file is probably still a better approach than just uploading it in place, since you will probably get some requests while the file is being written, which will cause errors.